# how to send the detailtextlabel date value to the date picker in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have an application in which i have a class where i am fetching values from database and displaying the values in the detailtextlabel of tableview.in the second cell of my tableview i am displaying the time selected from the database in the detailtextlabel.So my problem is the time that is displayed in the detailtextlabel should get displayed in the datepicker ,when  the second row is selected.when i select the second row i only get the current time in the date picker.This is my code:

```
   if (app.alarmtime) 
{
        [app.dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd:mm a"];
        NSLog(@"%@",app.alarmtime);
        NSDate *date = [app.dateFormatter dateFromString:app.alarmtime];

        NSLog(@"%@",date);
        datePicker.date = date;
}
    else
 {

         datePicker.date = [NSDate date];
```

}

al.Alarmtime is the variable where the database value is stored.
1>in this first log the value is displayed properly

2>but in the second nslog the value is returning null when i am converting string to nsdate.

Comment: I would suggest that either your thread always gets into 'else' condition (app.alarmtime is nil?..), or your (NSDate*)al.Alarmtime somehow returns current date :) Hard to say more from the code provided

Comment: Some questions arise: 1) Is `app.alarmtime` not nil or is it possible that that variable is not set correctly? 2) In your if branch you create a complete new `Alarm` object instead of using the `app.alarmtime`. Is this intentionaly? 3) Try adding some NSLog() to see what date exactly is being set in the datePicker and which branch is takes. This might shed some light on if the date picker does not accept the value or if the date value being set is always the current date/time.

Comment: @TriPhoenix i get this error in the console when i run the code Assertion failure in -[UIDatePickerView _updateBitsForDate:andReload:animateIfNeeded:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1447.6.4/UIDatePicker.m:1010
2011-11-29 16:01:36.228 StopSnooze[25776:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: date'

Comment: Definitely try putting something like `NSLog("true-branch: %@", date);` just before the `datePicker.date = date` to check the value in there. Could be that `al.Alarmtime` is not initialized properly.

Comment: can you post the log from NSLog(@"%@",app.alarmtime); ?

Comment: @Zoleas this is my log value from app.alarmtime : 17/11 11:22 AM (null)

Answer (score 0):

Your format is wrong, for the example you provided, the format should be :

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM hh:mm a '(null)'"];
```

In this case, the year would be 1970 because it is not provided by the NSString.

Comment: null is my second nslog value.i.e my second nslog is returning NULL .

Comment: if your app.alarmtime is equal to @"17/11 11:22 AM" then the good format is @"dd/MM hh:mm a"